# Android Retrofit how to make a Call parcelable?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, parcelable

I use retrofit as ReST Client in my android project and have different calls depending on which activity started an intent. I want to pass a Retrofit Call<> as parcelable. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm sorry but you can't, unless you change the library source code. You need to revaluate the strategy you're using. Why would you want to pass a call between activities? Whay don't you pass an ID indicating which activity originated the intenet and then in the destination activity you act on depedening on the value passed.?

Comment: You can't since Parcelables are supposed to only have literal values and not long living objects (Listeners) you better to have a Service and bind it in the second Activity

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit Call is not Parcelable and you should not pass it between activities (even if it was) since they have different Lifecycles.

I suggest having another class (like CallManager) which both activities have access to.

If you have Dependency Injection inside your app, you can inject it to both your activities. If not, just instantiate the class in a custom `Application` class and have it inside a public variable inside the Application class. That way you can access it inside your activities like `((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).getCallManager().callSomething(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a simple strategy while using retrofit 1.9 or 2 as it is not necessary at all to use parcelable inside retrofit call because retrofit calls having their own overridden methods and own cycle. 
Parcelable is used for passing data between objects so it is a good practice to keep them aside.  You can make a response and request object like natural retrofit calls. 
If you want you can use same objects which you used in your model class implementing parcelable in service ( where you define the end points ).